# PyQT Button click doesn't work

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

So my problem is that instead of manually writing a ton of code for a bunch of buttons, I want to create a class for a `QPushButton` and then change so many variables upon calling that class to create my individual buttons.

My problem is that my button does not seem to be clickable despite calling the clicked.connect function and having no errors upon running the code. Here are the relevant parts of the button class:

```
class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 90, 61, 51))
        self.setText("Change Me!")

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        self.clicked.connect(self.printSomething)

    def printSomething(self):
        print "Hello"
```

Here is how I call the button class:

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()
        self.btn = Button(self)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform the connection to the *clicked* signal on the `__init__` method:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 90, 61, 51))
        self.setText("Change Me!")
        self.clicked.connect(self.printSomething) #connect here!

    #no need for retranslateUi in your code example

    def printSomething(self):
        print "Hello"

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()
        self.btn = Button(self)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(layout)


app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = MyWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

You can run it and will see the *Hello* printed on the console every time you click the button.

The `retranslateUi` method is for i18n. You can check [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#reacting-to-language-changes).

Comment: Many thanks, I was stuck for hours and literally going nowhere, much appreciated!