# how to know that a pushbutton is clicked (Qt)?

Tags: python, qt-designer, qpushbutton

I'm trying to do a program with a board game and some pawns. I already created all the pawn's methods I needed (eg : move) and I am now working on my machine interface.

All the pawns and all the squares of the game board are represented by pushbuttons.

I want get the information "which pushbutton I clicked" in my code in order to create the following method :
If I clicked on pawn1 and clicked on square2 my pawn is going to move on square2 (if the movement is possible according to the rules).

So, can I get the information in order to create my method ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try looking at a question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29807630/10077) for clues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately your question only contains requirements: it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself.  Please [edit] your question to show [your attempt far](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and you'll be much more likely to receive answers that help you progress.  Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].